# Emulating signed integers using unsigned integers in C

Tags: c, integer, unsigned-integer

In Jens Gustedt's book Modern C, on page 59, he explains how signed integers can be emulated using unsigned integers.
His example code shows how one can implement a comparison of two unsigned integers reinterpreted as signed integers:

```
bool is_negative(unsigned a) { 
   unsigned const int_max = UINT_MAX /2;
   return a > int_max;
}

bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
   if (is_negative(b) && !is_negative(a)) return false;
   else return a < b; 
}
```

Do I misunderstand something here or does he miss the second special case where `is_negative(a) = true` and `is_negative(b) = false`?

For example if we want to have `a = -1` and `b = 1`, then, using two's complement, we would represent them as

```
unsigned int a = UINT_MAX; 
unsigned int b = 1;
```

(e.g. for a 4 bit integer we would have a = 1111 and b = 0001).
Now we have `is_negative(a)` returns `true`, and `is_negative(b)` returns `false`. When calling `is_signed_less(a, b)` we end up in the `else` clause and `a < b` (now interpreted as unsigned integers) will return false. However, it is clearly true that -1 < 1, so the function returns the wrong result.

Is this a typo in the code of the book or is there something that I do not understand?

Comment: Hmm, when the signs are the same, with 2's complement, `return a < b` suffices.  When signs differ, `return a > b`  should apply.

Comment: It is wrong, and a simpler solution is `#define Offset (UINT_MAX/2+1)` / `bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a+Offset < b+Offset; }`.

Comment: All this case-by-case stuff is inherently error-prone and it only gets worse when you start using comparisons (or XOR) between booleans.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what happens when people try to be "smart" instead of following "keep it simple, stupid" best practices. Good engineering involves writing the code as *simple* as you possibly can, for example:

```
bool is_signed_less_correct (unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  bool is_neg_a = is_negative(a);
  bool is_neg_b = is_negative(b);

  if(is_neg_a != is_neg_b) // one is negative
  {
    return is_neg_a; // if one is negative and it is a, return true otherwise false
  } 

  // both are negative or both are positive
  return a < b;
}
```

Even this code a bit too "smart" still, since it implicitly uses the fact that -1 == 0xFFFF... is the largest 2's complement signed number and therefore `a < b` holds true no matter if these are negative or not, as long as they are both of the same signedness.

Then of course you would always write a little unit test to sanity check it: https://godbolt.org/z/h4nKsffqr

Output:

```
-2 < -1 ? true  (is_signed_less_gustedt)
-1 < -1 ? false (is_signed_less_gustedt)
-1 <  0 ? false (is_signed_less_gustedt)
 0 < -1 ? false (is_signed_less_gustedt)
 0 <  1 ? true  (is_signed_less_gustedt)
 1 <  0 ? false (is_signed_less_gustedt)
 1 <  1 ? false (is_signed_less_gustedt)

-2 < -1 ? true  (is_signed_less_correct)
-1 < -1 ? false (is_signed_less_correct)
-1 <  0 ? true  (is_signed_less_correct)
 0 < -1 ? false (is_signed_less_correct)
 0 <  1 ? true  (is_signed_less_correct)
 1 <  0 ? false (is_signed_less_correct)
 1 <  1 ? false (is_signed_less_correct)
```

Answer (score 14):

As already [suggested by Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136366396) in the comments above, this is surely simpler and more efficient than the book version (or any of the other answers posted so far, AFAICT):

```c
bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
   unsigned const int_min = UINT_MAX / 2 + 1; /* 0x80000000 on 32-bit platforms */
   return (a - int_min) < (b - int_min); 
}
```

This code simply subtracts an offset from both of the inputs, so that the number representing the lowest possible signed integer value (`int_min`) is mapped to the lowest possible unsigned integer (`0`), and then does an unsigned comparison.

In particular, the subtraction maps the most negative signed integer (`int_min`) to 0, the second most negative signed integer (`int_min + 1`) to 1, the third most negative (`int_min + 2`) to 2, and so on.  Meanwhile, non-negative signed integers (whose bit patterns correspond to unsigned integers less than `int_min`) will cause the subtraction to wrap around, yielding values that are higher than those corresponding to any negative input.

---

Note that there are several possible (and equivalent) variations of this code.  For example, a curious numeric quirk of how fixed-width binary arithmetic works means that `int_min` is the unique unsigned integer for which `x + int_min`, `x - int_min` and `x ^ int_min` are all equal (for any `x`) — all of these operations just flip the most significant bit of `x`.  Thus, in the code above, the `-` operators can be replaced by either `+` or `^` without changing the behavior of the code in any way!

(There could *theoretically* be a small performance difference, if some of these operations happened to run faster or pipeline better on your CPU, and if your compiler wasn't smart enough to optimize them all into the same assembly code.  If you're worried that might be the case, benchmark them all and find out.  Most likely they'll all be equally fast, though.  Also, if you *really* want to obfuscate the code and confuse readers, try mixing and matching the operators into something like `return (a ^ int_min) < (int_min + b)`. :P)

Comment: Does this work correctly on one's complement or sign/magnitude C implementations, where `INT_MIN` is odd?  It might, but would leave one bit-pattern unused and wouldn't have the special properties you describe in the 2nd part of your answer for the 2's complement most-negative integer (just high bit set).  If you're trying to make a fully portable 2's complement implementation using unsigned binary math, don't use a constant that depends on the signed-integer representation.  `1 + (unsigned)INT_MAX` could work, or `UINT_MAX/2 + 1`

Comment: For those wondering (like I did), **unsigned** integer overflow is not undefined behaviour in C, and the result is well defined and guaranteed (signed integer overflow is).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thank you, that's a good point. It's probably safest to completely ignore how native signed ints are represented (including what the values of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` may be) and just define `unsigned const int_min = UINT_MAX / 2 + 1` to represent the most negative value among our emulated signed integers. I've edited my answer to correct it.

Comment: First, the point in the book is not about performance, whatever that could mean, here. It is meant to illustrate a concept (with the bug a rather failed one). There is no point in trying to be efficient. Nobody should ever do this in real life, compilers handle signed arithmetic far better. Second, starting with C23 there will be library (= builtin) support for checked arithmetic, so not even such a use case remains for such bit fiddling. Third, the context of that code in the book was two's complement representation, which, starting with C23, is the only sign representation that is left.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's an error. One way of resolving it is this:

```
bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    bool negativeA = is_negative(a);
    bool negativeB = is_negative(b);
    return (
        (
            negativeA != negativeB ?
            negativeA :
            a < b
        )
    );
}
```

First I computed `negativeA` and `negativeB`, respectively to avoid computing them again and again. Then, I checked if their sign differs.

Because if the sign of a and b differs and a is negative, then a < b.

Otherwise, if the sign of a and b is different and a is positive, then a > b.

In the other case, when their sign is the same, we simply compare them.

Comment: Anyway, the real point here is that we shouldn't try to be "smart" about supposedly simple stuff like this. I'm pretty sure that both you and Jens Gustedt are seasoned programmers, and yet here we are.

Comment: @Lundin apparently I had an error indeed but it was a misthinking on my part which may happen anytime when we did not test a code. I have applied a fix, thanks for pointing out the shortcoming of the answer and the downvote as well, but I have no issue using ternaries in such situations.

Comment: I'll delete my comments and I've revoked the downvote too. And well, there are 3 very similar answers now, just different choices of operators and local variables.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the comments and downvote anyways. It's always good to push the answerers to fix whatever mistakes they leave in their answers. Yes, the answers are pretty similar and differ in style. I think that's good, readers may choose what fits them the best for whatever reason they might have.

Comment: Btw a minor nitpick is that your version contains an implicit conversion to `int` and then back to `bool`. It's actually 100% equivalent to `(bool) (negativeA != negativeB ? (int)negativeA : a < b)`. Didn't affect the result here, but implicit conversions are to be avoided. This too was caused by the `?:` operator. Something like gcc `-Wconversion` might decide to whine over stuff like this too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is an error for the reason you specified.

In the case the signs are the same, using `a < b` works as normal.  If they differ, then we need to use `a > b` instead as all "negative" values are greater than all positive values.

```
bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
   if (is_negative(b) != is_negative(a)) return b < a;
   else return a < b;
}
```

Comment: You could even write `(is_negative(a ^ b))`, although I don't know which the compiler would prefer.

Comment: Wouldn't `!=` be even simpler?

Comment: @jcaron Yes it would!  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed Jens seems to have made a mistake...

Here is a simpler and hopefully correct version of this function:

```
bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
   const unsigned sign_bit = ~(UINT_MAX >> 1);
   return (a ^ sign_bit) < (b ^ sign_bit); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is a bug in the last edition of Modern C. I don't remember exactly when and how, but a correction has already made it in the C23 edition, which is to appear soon:

```
bool is_negative (unsigned a) {
    constexpr unsigned int_max = UINT_MAX/2;
    return a > int_max ;
}
bool is_signed_less (unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    if (is_negative (a) != is_negative (b)) return a > b ;
    else return a < b ;
}
```

I hope this is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the second-most obvious way:

```
bool is_signed_less(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  return is_negative(a-b);
}
```